# Proof Question: Set $\theta = \{((x^2,y),(y,2x,x-y)): x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ a function? What is domain, range, codomain?

Tags: solution-verification

Set $\theta = \{((x^2,y),(y,2x,x-y)): x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ a function? What is domain, range, codomain?

Domain: set of $(x^2,y)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Range: set of $(y,2x,x-y)$ for  $x,y \in\mathbb{Z}$ and the codomain is the same as the range.

This is a function because each set is "unique" from the previous set.

If I did this all correctly?

Comment: If x = (-1), then you get the same first-coordinate value for an element of $\theta$ as you would get for x = 1, but the second-coordinate values are different since (2*(-1)) isn't equal to (2*1), so $\theta$ isn't single-valued, so $\theta$ isn't a function.

Comment: @RenEhDaycart What about the third coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$((1^2,0),(0,2 \cdot 1,1-0)) = ((1,0),(0,2,1))$$ and $$(((-1)^2,0),(0,2 \cdot (-1),-1-0)) = ((1,0),(0,-2,-1))$$
both belongs to $\theta$.